# Will it still be possible to develop MacOS applications in C# after Xamarin End of Life

Tags: c#, xamarin

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android will both reach end of life in May 2024. The official Microsoft announcement details how you can migrate these apps to .Net7.

However, there is no mention of MacOS apps built using Xamarin.Mac. Is there any upgrade path for developers wanting to continue with C# for Mac applications?

Comment: you can build desktop Mac apps with MAUI

Comment: @Jason Yes, that would be an option, but I have apps with native UI done in Xcode and I'd like to continue to develop them that way.

Comment: I think that's possible because MAUI is built on top of the individual iOS/Mac/Android frameworks, but I don't know how well documented/supported that approach is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the documentation is a bit lacking in this area. But native mac with appkit is still fully supported.

See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/native-projects

It mentions Xamarin.Mac. But does not give much in examples. You can follow a similar procedure as discribed for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android
The targetframework you need to use is

```
<TargetFramework>net7.0-macos</TargetFramework>
```

As .Net Maui does NOT support the macos target (only maccatalyst) you cannot use Maui Essentials as a replacement for Xamarin.Essentials. So if you are using that you need to find other libraries for the features you are using or bring some of the Xamarin.Essentials code into your project.

Answer (score 1):

.NET MAUI (which is essentially a rebrand of Xamarin) [supports MacCatalyst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui):

> macOS apps built using .NET MAUI use Mac Catalyst, a solution from Apple that brings your iOS app built with UIKit to the desktop, and augments it with additional AppKit and platform APIs as required.

Comment: That is an option for new apps, but I have some existing apps written directly for MacOS using C# without starting life as iOS apps or using MacCatalyst. I'm looking for an equivalent path for Xamarin.Mac as Microsoft provided for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Well I guess you are out of luck then. I don't think anything like that exists. They do provide a migration tool though I haven't worked with (plain) Mac before. Maybe it could help?

Comment: This is not correct. Pure native macos with appkit is still supported . You can ugrade a native Xamarin.Mac to net6-macos or net7-macos.

Comment: @svn that's good to hear for OP if this is what he needs. Still, does that mean it's basically in "life-support" mode as there won't be future update? I don't think you should write new app if that's the case.

Comment: @LukeVo The macos target is supported in the upcomming .NET 8 which is a long term support release:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/8.0/supported-os.md
I could not find any other other policy documents on support for any Os in the long term after that

Comment: This phrase that can cause some confusion:
.NET MAUI (which is essentially a rebrand of Xamarin).
And I blame microsoft for that. As they are pushing MAUI allot and do not mention native as much. But .Net MAUI is a more rebrand of Xamarin.Forms.
Xamarin support itself is now just baked into .NET
And MAUI actually uses the native components to implement the UI on each platform

Answer (score 1):

Update (Nov 7, 2023): I confirmed that net8.0-macos, net8.0-ios, and net8.0-android apps can all be developed in Visual Studio for Mac (17.6.6) if that environment is preferred to using the dotnet cli approach of the original response. Also, these apps can all be developed in f# (and probably Visual Basic too). To do so:

1. After installing the latest .net8 sdk, in Visual Studio for Mac preferences, go to 'Preview Features' under the 'Other' section, and check 'Use the .NET 8 SDK if installed' option.
2. I believe that the .net8 ios and android workloads can be installed from within Visual Studio for Mac, but for me using the command line wass a bit more reliable: '(sudo) dotnet workload install ios android'. At this point, you can build .net8 macos, ios, and android apps in c# in Visual Studio for Mac. To build f# apps, continue as follows.
3. For net8.0-macos, follow the f# instructions from the original response for using the 'dotnet new macos' approach (i.e. re-run the Visual Studio for Mac installer if you don't see the .net macos app template, copy over f# files from a xamarin-macos f# app, include them in the .fsproj file, and change the .csproj file ending to .fsproj). The .sln file must also be changed to recognize the .fsproj file. This is described in step 7.
4. For net8.0-ios, create a xamarin-ios f# app in Visual Studio for Mac and add the AppDelegate.fs, ViewController.fs, and Main.fs from the xamarin-ios app into the net8.0-ios app. Delete the .cs files in the net8.0-ios app.
5. For net8.0-android, create a xamarin-android f# app and copy over MainActivity.fs into the net8.0-android project. You do NOT need to copy over the AssemblyInfo.fs file. There are some differences between the MainActivity.fs and the corresponding MainActivity.cs files. Modify the code in the MainActivity.fs file as shown below, using an appropriate namespace, to match the MainActivity.cs code:

```
namespace AndroidApp

// open System

open Android.App
// open Android.Content
open Android.OS
// open Android.Runtime
// open Android.Views
// open Android.Widget

[<Activity (Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true)>]
type MainActivity () =
    inherit Activity ()

    override this.OnCreate (savedInstanceState:Bundle) =

        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState)

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        this.SetContentView (Resource.Layout.activity_main)
```

Note: many of the xamarin.android using/open statements are no longer required in .net8. Remove the .cs files.

6. For .net8.0-ios and .net8-android apps, change the .csproj file ending to .fsproj. And, include the new files in the .fsproj folder. e.g. add the lines:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AppDelegate.fs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewController.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Main.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

or

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MainActivity.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note: the original xamarin-macos, xamarin-ios, and xamarin-android .fsproj files have a lot more lines referencing things like the info.plist file, etc. These are NOT needed for the .net8 apps.

7. Finally, but importantly, you must also edit the .sln files. Change the reference to the .csproj file to the .fsproj file that replaces it. You must also change the project guid. For the c# project, it will be: 'FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC'. For an f# project, change it to: 'F2A71F9B-5D33-465A-A702-920D77279786'. (If these numbers change, just make an f# project and extract the correct project guid number from the .sln file).
8. I think that should do it. In Visual Studio for Mac, you will see a bunch of red squiggly lines in some of the f# files, as there may not be references to them in the .fsproj file. But those assemblies and modules will be brought in at build time even without explicit mention in the .fsproj files. At this point, you should be able to use f# to build macos, ios, and android apps under .net8, or at least get starter apps to build and run. I imagine .net maccatalyst and .net maui apps can probably also be built as f# apps, but there are no xamarin file templates for those apps, so you'll need to build the files by hand.

--
Original response follows:

Visual Studio for Mac (17.6.5) does not seem to provide a starting template for a .net8 Mac app to bring your code into, even after installing .net8. Here's a working example as of Nov 4, 2023 using the dotnet cli and .net SDK 8.0.100-rc.2. to generate the starter app to fill in with your code.

1. Install .net 8.0 for your platform, if not already installed. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0.
2. Check version: 'dotnet --version'.
3. Install the macos workload: 'dotnet workload install macos'. You can run 'dotnet workload list' to make sure that it's there.
4. Make a new directory for your app and cd there. Run 'dotnet new macos' to install the template files. (At this point, I initially received a template name collision error with 'Falco.Template'. I ran 'dotnet new uninstall Falco.Template' to remove the conflicting template'). Run 'dotnet run' and a native Mac window should appear.
5. At this point, you should see project files with names similar to a starting Xamarin.Mac project, including a 'Main.storyboard' file to design the UI in xcode. The .csproj file will look like the project file in the upgrade example:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-macos</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>true</ImplicitUsings>
  <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>10.15</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

6. I confirmed that you can publish the Mac app as an AOT native app. Just add a 'PublishAot true' line in your project file:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-macos</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>true</ImplicitUsings>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>10.15</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

7. Then create the native executable with 'dotnet publish -r osx-arm64 -c Release' or 'dotnet publish -r osx-x64 -c Release' as appropriate. Note: you'll have to actually open/run the generated executable yourself; the dotnet cli only generates it.

With the approach, you can now target osx 10.15 for your Mac app, which you can't with Xamarin.Mac. You can create the project in Visual Studio for Mac targeting OSX 14.0, but as of Xamarin.Mac 9.3.0 the maximum build target is osx 13.3 and the build will fail.

As a bonus, 'dotnet new macos' supports a language flag for Visual Basic ('dotnet new macos -lang VB'), but not f#. However, f# can be used to make .net 8 mac apps; but you have to add the f# files by hand, and then tweak the project file. Here is one way to do so:

1. Make a new folder and cd into it. Run 'dotnet new macos' (after having followed the earlier example to install .net 8 and load the macos workload).
2. Delete the created files 'Main.cs', 'AppDelegate.cs', 'ViewController.cs', and 'ViewController.designer.cs'.
3. Rename the *.csproj file to *.fsproj (i.e. just change the file ending).
4. Create new files named AppDelegate.fs and Main.fs. Add code to these files; the code is the same as in the corresponding files in a new Xamarin.Mac project:

```
// AppDelegate.fs
namespace Application
open System
open Foundation
open AppKit

[<Register ("AppDelegate")>]
type AppDelegate () =
    inherit NSApplicationDelegate ()
```

and,

```
// Main.fs
namespace Application
open AppKit

module main =
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =
        NSApplication.Init ()
        NSApplication.Main (args)
        0
```

5. Add the appropriate compile tags to the project file. Order matters. The final .fsproj file, at this point, looks like:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-macos</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>true</ImplicitUsings>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>10.15</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AppDelegate.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Main.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

6. At this point, you should be able to run 'dotnet run' in the folder, build and run the project, and see a native Mac window.
7. If you wish to interact with the "ViewController" customClass named in the Main.Storyboard file programmatically, you'll need to add one more file, 'ViewController.fs':

```
// ViewController.fs
namespace Application

open Foundation
open AppKit

[<Register ("ViewController")>]
type ViewController(handle:nativeint) =
    inherit NSViewController(handle)

    override this.ViewDidLoad() =
        ()
```

and then modify the .fsproj file to include the new file:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-macos</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>true</ImplicitUsings>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>10.15</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AppDelegate.fs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewController.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Main.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

You can also generate the AOT native executable for the f# project, as above for the c# project. That should do it!